# Nameserver Translation

Tags: dns, subdomain

My webserver gives me nameserver addresses to allow me to configure my domain to my server.

```
dns.hostingcompany.com
ns.hostingcompany1.com
```

I have several clients that I manage their domain name on this server. Currently I have to give them the above nameservers so their domains works.

Is it possible to setup some dns records where I can give them more professional nameserver addresses, and they just get resolved to the normal ones.

```
ns.mysite.com
ns.mysite.net
```